# How to :hover one div on two other divs and make it dynamic with JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hover this div on 2 more divs, and this div additionally should go on its position dynamically maybe playing with the `$(document).width();`

So, an example is the following:

```html
<div id="store">
     <div id="storeText">Store</div>
</div>
<div id="score">
     <div id="money">Money earned: 0</div>
     <div id="times">Bulbs charged: 0</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#score {
background-color: #aaaaaa;
width: 96%;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%; }

#store {
float:right;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
width: 10%;
height: 200px;
margin: 0;
padding: 19px 2% 19px 2%; }

#storeText {
text-align: center; }
```

That's what I should do, but you need to consider I have one more div in the bottom and this is what happens:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snip3r_bow/9dojufhn/)

So my question is, how can I position that div '#store' dynamically on that position (right) noting that it should hover all the divs and not make them go away as it actually does right now.

If you didn't get how the result should be, this [link](http://hideme.altervista.org/Untitled-2.jpg) will help you understand it carefully.

Comment: As per my understand you want to show score div on mouse hover to store div?

Comment: Mh no: I want to do the same thing in the image you see in the last link, but by default, then no with hovering mouse or click events

Comment: The 'hover' I have used stand for 'something above something' where something here is a div.@Jani

Comment: I can't open that image now due to some network problem. So i need your question by words only.

Comment: Okay not a problem, so: Imagine that I have 3 colored divs okay? Green (1) White (2) Red (3). The 1st one is placed like a Nav bar in the top of the document; the third one is in the rest of the body, and the second one is that one I need 'above' all the others(to make it clear, consider it as a z-index thing: the second one should have the z-index higher to stand above of all of the others with a minor z-index)

Comment: I understand your problem. One more question . if 2nd div above 1st and 3rd div then how you identify code is working or not.

Comment: Forget about anything: I have fixed the issue, but I don't like it and plus I started over to design a little 'User Interface'. I already have some ideas on it but, shall I create a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jani123/pex7Ldq7/1/)

What i understand from you i put here, please let me know if you want any more help.

```css
#store {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
}
#score {
    float:right;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
   }
#storeText {
    text-align: center;
}
#div3 {
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.4;
    
    padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="store">
    <div id="storeText">Store</div>
</div>
<div id="score">
    <div id="money">Money earned: 0</div>
    <div id="times">Bulbs charged: 0</div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I asked for but as I told you I did fix it already (but thanks a lot anyway eh ;) ) Now my issue is this: I'd like to design a little UI: Just 2 divs side by side held by another single div, the parent one, note I want to add text on both of them and centered